# Only Firefox TypeError: "NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource."

Tags: javascript, web, firefox, resources, fetch

I have a page which loads content dynamically, and I make several calls to backends API's all these calls have the same configuration, like this:

```
function get_data_1(){
  var data = {
    type: "home"    
  };
  
  fetch('../backend/get/slider.php',  {
      method: 'POST',      
      credentials: 'same-origin',
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
      headers:{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    })
    .then(function(response) {      
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(response) {            
      if( response.success ){
       //here proceses de code
      } else {               
       //here proceses de code if not success response
      }
    })
    .catch( function(error){      
      console.error(error);
      //Here is where the error catch and show the error: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource
  });
```

When the page load, call many functions like this:

get_data_1();
get_data_2();
...

All the responses of the backend API have the same output format (JSON) and have the same headers, I'm using an only server (localhost), but only some calls get the error and others work fine, the problem is only with Firefox with chrome, opera, and edge I no have any error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the reason why some request has not a response, is a bug with the ad blocker that I have installed in Firefox when I disable the ad blocker, all works fine

Comment: How strange. Did you investigate further? I found myself with the same problem - most fetch requests to the server worked but one or two failed consistently every time. Thanks to your answer I tracked it down to uBlock Origin, but I would never have guessed this otherwise. Obviously I would prefer not to have certain features of my website disabled for adblock users.

Comment: Effectively the requests blocked have references to ads, for this reason, the adblocker was making his job. But changing the name of the requests and parameters with no references to words associated with ads is one way to prevent that this request will be blocked